# Swift 4 - Cannot invoke 'encode' with an argument list of type '(Codable)'

Tags: json, swift, codable, encodable

I have built a set of API functions which encode an object (using a `Struct` which conforms to `Codable`), then Posts the resulting JSON Data object to a server, then decodes the JSON response. All works fine - especially happy with the new method for JSON parsing in Swift 4.2. However, now I want to refactor the code so that I can reuse the code for various method calls - when I do I get a really annoying error.

```
func encodeRequestJSON(apiRequestObject: Codable) -> Data {
    do {
        let encoder = JSONEncoder()
        let jsonData = try encoder.encode(apiRequestObject)
        let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)
        print(jsonString)
    } catch {
        print("Unexpected error")
        }
    return jsonData!
}
```

This is the error message:

```
Cannot invoke 'encode' with an argument list of type '(Codable)'
```

I have tried changing the type from Codable, to Encodable but get the same error, except with type (Encodable) in the message. Any advice? My fall-back is to encode the data in the current ViewController, then call the HTTPPost function and then decode back in the VC. But that's really clunky.

Comment: You need to specify the exact type while using `Codable`. You can't generalize it with protocol as a type.

Comment: Note that if you click on the "more info" of the error, you should get `1. Expected an argument list of type '(T)'` which can be related to Dávid Pásztor's answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need a concrete type to be passed into `JSONEncoder.encode`, so you need to make your function generic with a type constraint on `Encodable` (`Codable` is not needed, its too restrictive).

```
func encodeRequestJSON<T:Encodable>(apiRequestObject: T) throws -> Data {
    return try JSONEncoder().encode(apiRequestObject)
}
```